replacing a specific character from a string doesn't work in JavaScript
I need to replace all the \" in the string to \' but the issue is whenever I try to do either, it's not detecting or replacing it and gives me same string output with \" character.


function replaceEscapedQuotes(inputString) {
    return inputString.replace(/\\"/g, "\\'");
}


const jsonString = `{\"aaData\":[{\"assetType_DisplayNameEnabled\":\"true\",\"assetType_Color\":\"#FDBD37\"}]}`;
const replacedString = replaceEscapedQuotes(jsonString);

console.log(JSON.stringify(replacedString));
console.log("Length:", replacedString.length); 



edit:so many people were asking me why to do it,actually My API gives me:"<a href=\"https://fly.localhost.com/?page_id=42\" rel=\"noopener\" target=\"_blank\">CDM Hub System </a></p>"}],"FullName":"Aggregate Demand Logs - RF","DisplayName":"Aggregate Demand Logs - RF","Id":"16f53da4-bb8b-4efb-ab50-8cf545061198","AssetType_Color":"#FDBD37","AssetType_SymbolType":"ICON_CODE"
The above is response from my API in string format. when i try to parse it i am getting errors such as VM71:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 1 where when i replace all of my
\"
with  \' it solves my issue

Why do you need to replace that? IT's valid JSON, you will make it invalid by replacing those.

The backslash does not exist in the string. It is in the code to escape the quote. If you really want to replace the double quotes with single: return inputString.replace('"', "'")

why would you want to stringify  already stringified json?

.replace(/\\"/g - you are not in the context of a double-quoted text literal here, so the double quote character does not need escaping. And the replacement should probably rather be only a single quote, and not additional backslashes, I suppose? -> .replace(/"/g, "'")

As noted above, \"`and`"` are the same thing: ``console.log(".length)``   If the string was `{\"A...\"`then you would need/\"/g`

The problem is here:
inputString.replace(/\\"/g, "\\'");

You don't need to escape non-regex characters in a regex, so /\\"/ is looking for two backslashes and a ", which you don't have.
Instead, you need
inputString.replace(/\"/g, "\\'");

You still need the double backslash for the replacement string because you're now in a string context, so escaping is necessary.
As others have noted, there are a number of problems with what you appear to be doing. For one, " is the valid quote character for JSON strings.
For another, you're calling stringify on a string. While syntactically valid, this seems like an odd thing to do. One would expect you to be parsing the string instead. However, this will fail, if you change the quote characters to 's.
